# Protocol for device tracking

Tags: java, m2m

I want to create a server through which i can track devices(mobile,vechile etc etc).
How can i create a protocol that can accept commands from all type of devices.

Comment: This is a very generic question. Also this is not particularly a JAVA question. If its a design question it should be marked as that. I would recommend you to look at how JDBC is implemented and follow the pattern. Write an interface and for each device type write a protocol driver. And for each device type you have a record that identifies what device type it is on server end to use the correct driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to support TCP or UDP requests assuming they support IP. I would suggest getting TCP to work first.  I would send what you need to send in the simplest Text or Binary format you can come up with.

If they don't support IP I suggest creating a gateway which support the transport they support already and pass this to TCP so your server has a common transport and protocol to talk to.

Comment: like mobiles and vehciles that i want to track dosn't supports IP..
so i need to create a gateway that can accept commands from that vehcile hardware tracking system... this is what u r suggesting?

Comment: Its hard to be more specific without any details of what transports your devices support, or what you are doing.

Comment: suppose there is one mobile phone and one vechile...what i want to do is.. i will create a web application where i can display mobile tracking details and vehcile tracking details...

Comment: vehciles will have some tracking hardware taht will send commands through GPS.and my server need to accept this command and track the details

Comment: `send commands through GPS` you can't do that unless you have hacked the US military satellites which produce GPS signals. In which case, you are in the wrong job. ;)  You need to know how these devices really work technically.

Comment: lolzz  :P  i mean by GPS that tracking hardware will know the location and send this location to server via mobile network.

Comment: Ok, so how does it send via the mobile network? SMS? To an SMS Gateway which can talk IP?

Comment: OK so you need your SMS Gateway to take SMS messages and pass them to your service.  Does it have a TCP or UDP protocol/API it supports already?

Comment: this is what i am seeking help for...how can i create such a application that will accept SMS from tracking device??

Comment: I would use an existing SMS gateway application https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+sms+gateway There are plenty available so I wouldn't write one from scratch.